# FragmentManager.beginTransaction() cannot be applied to (int, android.app.fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a navigation drawer in Android and I have run into a bit of a problem. I have a method in my MainActivity.java that handles my clicks on the navigation drawer and directs the user to the proper activity. The method as shown here:

```
      @Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    android.app.Fragment objFragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            objFragment= new menu1_Fragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            objFragment = new menu2_Fragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            objFragment = new menu3_Fragment();
            break;
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, objFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

My problem is that I get an error on the third to last line in `.replace(R.id.container, objFragment)` : `FragmentTransaction cannot be applied to (int, android.app.fragment)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use support Fragments if you use the `SupportFragmentManager`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html

vs

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

You can never mix and match between the two

```
// update the main content by replacing fragments
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment objFragment = null;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
```

---

clarity, replace:

`android.app.Fragment objFragment = null;`

with

`android.support.v4.app.Fragment objFragment = null;`

Comment: I thought I already called the `SupportFragmentManager` when it invoked `getSupportFragmentManager();`?

Comment: no you need to use support Fragments is what I'm saying

Comment: I did all of the above edits, but now I have errors on the cases in the switch statement, an error of `incompatible types`

Comment: now you have to go into `menu1_Fragment` and ensure it is extending the correct `Fragment`